# EF Core, efficient way of adding a multitude of large entities to the many-to-many relationship of another entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

lets say I have two Models, Tags and Posts, and the Tag Model is very large (lots of columns). A Tag can have Multiple posts, and a Post can have multiple Tags.

The only way I know how to set relationships between Tags and Posts is by doing

```
var veryLargeTagList = context.Tags.Where(some logic).ToArray();
myPost.Tags.AddRange(veryLargeTagList);
```

My question is, this seems to require loading in a lot of tags into memory, what would be the most efficient (Quickest/Memory efficient) way to add these tags to the post? Is there a way to add tags to post using just the tags id? like so:

```
var veryLargeTagList = context.Tags.Where(some logic).Select(e=>e.Id).ToArray();
myPost.Tags.AddRange(veryLargeTagList);
```

Comment: _"what would be the most efficient (Quickest/Memory efficient) way to add these tags to the post?"_ - Probably a custom `PROCEDURE` within your database that you invoke via `DbContext`. Remember that EF/EFCore, like all ORMs, exists to make software faster to develop, and _not necessarily_ to make software faster to run. For many nontrivial things, and where performance matters, I find it's easier just to get the `SqlConnection` directly from the `DbContext` and issue my own `SqlCommands`.

Comment: I don't see a post-tag model. Do you have one?

Comment: @SalmanA Negative, My models different, used post and tag as an alias because its the models Microsoft uses for its tutorials here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a junction table? That would be one way to add with only the IDs.

You create a junction table that only has the PostId and the TagId. Then you add the relationships there.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that this is what the many-to-many relationship was doing behind the hood? I'll try this and let you know if see improvement, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use two ways

1.
you can to use tsql to bulk-insert

```
create proc insertPost
 @Text nvarchar(100)

as

insert into Posts
(Text,created,tageID)
select @Text,GETDATE(),Id
from Tags
where some logic
```

2. 

you can use bulk-insert

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
{

   BatchSize = 1024

};
var subEntities = new List<PostTag>();
SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
string text = "";
int PostId = context.Post.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Text == text).ID;

subEntities = context.Tags.Where(some logic).Select(t => new PostTag { PostId = PostId, TagId = t.ID }).ToList();
await context.BulkInsertAsync(subEntities, bulkConfig);
```

Link to BulkExtensions library: [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

Link to BulkExtensions Learn:[LearnBulkExtensions](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/bulk-extensions/bulk-insert)